# Dynamic combobox doesn't update

Tags: php, html, ajax, combobox

I'm trying to make a combobox that when another combobox is changed it will dynamically update with information from a database. I'm finding a lot of solutions that do not seem to work with what I have and am lost on what to do next.

I've tried simplifying the code to figure out what part does not work, there are so many different versions of the code I tried I just know that some of the one I have right now works and some of it does not.

EDIT: better code (I hope)

Database connexion (root/config/config.php)

```
<?php
    define("DB_HOST", "10.172.16.4");
    define("DB_USER", "test2_user");
    define("DB_PASS", "password");
    define("DB_NAME", "test2");

    $dsn = "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME;
    $options = [PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];
    try { 
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
    } catch (PDOException $error) {
        echo "Connection error: " . $error->getMessage();
        die();
    }
?>
```

Header (root/online/templates/header.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

The form (root/online/create.php)

```
<?php
    require_once "templates/header.php";
    require_once "../config/config.php";
 ?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <label for="choose_type">Type</label>
    <select name="choose_type_modele" id="choose_type" onchange="selectMarque()" required>
        <option value="">Select Type</option>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM typeMateriel";
            if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $typeMateriel = $stmt->fetchAll();
                }
            }
            foreach($typeMateriel as $foundType){
                $typeMateriel_id = $foundType['id'];
                $typeMateriel_name = $foundType['name'];
        ?>
        <option value="<?= $typeMateriel_id; ?>"><?= $typeMateriel_name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <label for="choose_marque">Marque</label>
    <select name="choose_marque_modele" id="choose_marque" required>
        <option value="">Select type first</option>
    </select>
</form>
<p id="test"></p>
<?php require_once "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

The function (root/online/js/javascript.php)

```
function selectMarque() {
    var typeID = $('#choose_type').val();
    var post_id = 'id='+ typeID;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "You Selected " + typeID;
        if(typeID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'../ajax_marque.php',
                data:post_id,
                success:function(marque){
                    $('#choose_marque').html(marque);
                }
            });
        }else{
            document.getElementById("choose_marque").innerHTML = '<option value="">Select type first</option>';
        }
};
```

the code for the dynamic stuff (root/online/ajax_marque.php)

```
<?php
include('../config/config.php');
if($_POST['id']){
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    if($id===0){
        echo "<option>N/A</option>";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT marqueMateriel.id,marqueMateriel.name FROM type_marque, marqueMateriel WHERE marqueMateriel.id=type_marque.marqueMateriel_id AND type_marque.typeMateriel_id= :typeMateriel_id";
        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bindParam(':typeMateriel_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $marqueMateriel = $stmt->fetchAll();
            }
        }
        echo "<option>Select Marque</option>";
        foreach($marqueMateriel as $foundMarque) {
            $marqueMateriel_id = $foundMarque['id'];
            $marqueMateriel_name = $foundMarque['name'];
            echo "<option value='<?php $marqueMateriel_id; ?>'><?php $marqueMateriel_name; ?></option>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Closing up (root/online/template/Footer.php)

```
</body>
</html>
```

The first combo box works, and that's pretty much it. Nothing changes and I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere. I can use the function to alert(typeID) and it does so , but not change the data :/

EDIT : Trying to make more sense ?

The combo box "choose_type_modele" works, it contains everything from the table "typeMateriel". When I select something it does not change the second box "choose_marque_modele". The onchange function is called, as the "test" is modified on selection with the appropriate ID. The code in "ajax_marque.php" works if I copy it inside "create.php" and manually tell it what "$id" is, but it won't do it automatically. I feel the problem is the $.ajax part of the code inside "javascript.js" but I cannot seem to figure out what part is wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `$stmt` here?

Comment: You also want to read up on prepared statements with parameters, and also you need to escape output before inserting it into HTML.

Comment: Ok, we got it doesn't change data. But what it does? This works has 3 parts. 1st: Send request when checkbox changed. 2nd: Recieve request by php and prepare and send response. 3rd: Recieve php's response and create options. In which part does the code fails?

Comment: The only part that does not work is the one that changes the data of the second combobox. The first one works, the onchange works (if I make it do anything else). If I had the php of ajax_marque.php inside the create.php it works, the only time it does not work is when I call it with ajax. @Mehmet

Comment: Thank for your help, I'm not asking for how to make this safe in any way, I deleted most of the code to make it less confusing, I'm sorry it was not a good job @miken32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two errors in my code that made it impossible to work, the url and success parts of the ajax code.

Working code :

```
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajax_marque.php',
                data:post_id,
                success:function(data){
                    $('#choose_marque').html(data);
                }
            });
```

For some reason I had "marque" instead of data (I might have changed it thinking it was something else ? ) and the url was "../ajax_marque.php". I thought I had to add the url from wherever the javascript.php file was, not from where it was called (create.php).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if you can add options to a select with `html` method. You have to create `option` objects to add `select` object. To archieve this, you'll change response of your ajax method to JSON object.

```js
var selectMarque = function() {

  // Remove current options from matque
  $('#choose_marque').find("option").remove();

  var typeID = $('#choose_type').val();
  var post_id = 'id=' + typeID;

  // There will be always value in post_id
  // You have to check typeID to be sure if type picked

  if (typeID) {

    // sample ajax data
    var testData = [{
        "value": "1",
        "text": "Option 1"
      },
      {
        "value": "2",
        "text": "Option 2"
      },
    ];

    // for each option data in testData
    $.each(testData, function(offset, optionData) {
      // append an option to select
      $('#choose_marque').append($('<option>', {
        value: optionData.value,
        text: optionData.text
      }));
    });

  } else {
    // if empty value picked as type
    // add sample option to marque

    $('#choose_marque').append($('<option>', {
      value: "",
      text: "Select Type To Fill"
    }));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="choose_type_modele" id="choose_type" onchange="selectMarque()" required>
  <option value="">Select Type</option>
  <option value="1">Fill Select</option>
</select>

<select id="choose_marque" required>
  <option value="">Select Type To Fill</option>
</select>
```